# Galois group of $K(\sqrt[p]a)$ over $K$

Tags: galois-theory

If $p$ is a prime number and $a$ is an element of the field $K$, what can be said about the Galois group of $K(\sqrt[p]a)$ over $K$? (That is, $\sqrt[p]a$ is an element whose $p$-th power is $a$)

I was hoping to show it's a cyclic group of order $p$, and then use that to show that the Galois group of a polynomial solvable in radicals is solvable. I thought I could do this by showing that $[K(\sqrt[p]a):K]=p$, but I think that might actually be false. I think it's true for primitive roots of unity, but it's not clear to me what general conditions need to be imposed on $\sqrt[p]a$ in order to make this work.

Can anything like what I want be proven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the field $K$ contains the p-th roots of unity, then $K(\sqrt[p]{a})$ is a splitting field of the irreductible polynomial $P=X^p-a$ (of course we suppose that a is not a p-th power), so is galoisien of degree p. The roots of $P$ are $\mu ^j \sqrt[p]{a}$ where $\mu$ is a generator of the group of p-th roots of unity. In this case the galois group is cyclic of order p (sent $\sqrt[p]{a}$ to $\mu ^k \sqrt[p]{a}$).

Comment: So alternatively, instead of assuming $K$ contains the $p$-th roots of unity, can we consider $K(r_1, ... r_p)$, where the $r_i$ are all of the roots of $P$?

Comment: Of course yes. But if $K$ does not contain the p-th roots of unity, the Galois group will not be cylic of order p. We could consider the tower of extensions: $K\hookrightarrow K(\mu _p)\hookrightarrow K(\mu _p, \sqrt[p]{a})$. We will obtain a injective morphism of the Galois group into the one dimensional affine transformation group over $\mathbb{F}_p$: $Gal \rightarrow GA_1(\mathbb{F}_p)$

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Why do you think $X^p-a$ is irreducible ?

Comment: Ok I got it : whenever $gcd(n,p) = 1$ the morphism generated $\varphi(a) = a \mu_p^k$ is clearly in the Galois group, so the minimal polynomial of $a^{1/p}$ must have each $a \mu_p^k$ in its roots, and hence it is $X^p-a$